# How to do data tables in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am fetching records from database and converting data into json array. I am getting json response correctly. but table shows no entry in my view.. please see once . Thanks.

my controller

```html
function test() {

          
    $list = $this->get_data_model->get_apartment_details();
        $data = array();
        $no = $_POST['start'];
        foreach ($list as $apartments) {
            $no++;
            $row = array();
            $row[] = $no;
            $row[] = $apartments->a_id;
            $row[] = $apartments->a_name;
            $data[] = $row;
        }

           $output = array(  
                "draw"                    =>     5,  
                "recordsTotal"          =>      2,
                "recordsFiltered"     =>     1,
                "data"                    =>    $data
           ); 
         
  echo json_encode($output);//
 }
```

my view

```html
<section  class="tab-pane fade in active" id="newPanel">
              
                  <table style='width:100%'' class='table' id='example'>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                             <th> ID </th>
                             <th> Name </th>
                             <th> Activate  </th>
                             <th> Edit </th>
                             </tr>
                        </thead>
                       

                   </table> 
             </section>
```

my ajax call

```html
$('#example').DataTable( {
       
        "processing" : true,
        "serverSide" : true,
        "ajax" : {
                  
                   "type" : "POST",
                   "url": "<?php echo base_url("apartments/test");?>",
                   "dataSrc" : ""
                  
                 },

       "columns": [
                 { "data": "a_id"},
                 { "data": "a_name" }
                
            ],


  "dom": 'Bfrtip',
        "buttons": [
            {
                "extend": 'copyHtml5',
                "exportOptions": {
                 "columns": ':contains("Office")'
                }
            },
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ]
           
           
    } );
} );
```

Comment: if you want you can use this http://opendatatable.com alternative of datatables

Answer (score 0):

Your Table ID attribute and your ajax call id attribute is different. hope below code will help you.

```
$('#newPanel').DataTable( {

        "processing" : true,
        "serverSide" : true,
        "ajax" : {

                   "type" : "POST",
                   "url": "<?php echo base_url("apartments/test");?>",
                   "dataSrc" : ""

                 },

       "columns": [
                 { "data": "a_id"},
                 { "data": "a_name" }

            ],


        "dom": 'Bfrtip',
        "buttons": [
            {
                "extend": 'copyHtml5',
                "exportOptions": {
                 "columns": ':contains("Office")'
                }
            },
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ]


    } );
} );
```